# Is the Ulam Spiral just a coincidence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, prime-numbers

I noticed that if you lay out the Ulam spiral and then circle all the even numbers, it displays a perfect array of diagonal lines. If this is true, then naturally you would see diagonal lines in the Ulam Spiral with prime numbers, because they would have to lie between the even diagonal lines (Primes cannot be even, except for $2$). To me the broken up diagonal lines of the Ulam spiral just seem to be an illusion, because of the prime numbers' forced existence on the odd diagonal lines.

Comment: In this video is an explanation: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=iFuR97YcSLM

Comment: @Neal well as you probably know indeed the discovery of the pattern by Ulam was a coincidence :) Well apart from that (very poor sorry) joke, even if it is just a coincidence in terms of the location of the primes, It is very interesting to visualize prime polynomials, but imho I think there are better ways of representing (at least second and third degree) prime polynomials in a 2D space.

Comment: Mathematics doesn't have coincidences !!!! That's why it is found everywhere .

Answer (score 2):

Your first observation is correct: except for the prime 2, all of the even lines in the number spiral are devoid of primes.  But that is not the main point.  If you focus only on the odd lines, it is evident that some have a lot of primes, some have a middling number, some have very few, and some have almost none.  It is this wide variance that people find striking (but not wholly unexpected—see the Wikipedia article for some insight into why these density variances occur).

Some things you can try:

1. make an Ulam spiral with only odd numbers.  The absence of the empty even lines makes it harder to see what's going on, but you should still be able to detect the same variations in density as in the usual Ulam spiral.
2. make a number spiral (with both even and odd numbers).  Instead of marking the primes, mark odd numbers randomly, letting the probability that $n$ is marked be $1/\log(n)$.  (This is roughly proportional to the probability that $n$ is prime.)  The result will not have anything like the density variances that are seen in the Ulam spiral, which tells you that this is not simply an odd/even effect.

Comment: It might have been more accurate if, instead of saying "But that is not the main point", I had said "But that is not the whole point." The effect you describe is the effect of the prime 2 on the positions of all subsequent primes, which is the most visible effect.  But there is also the effect of the prime 3 on the position of subsequent primes, the effect of the prime 5, the effect of 7, and so on. The cumulative effect of all the primes is to produce a highly irregular and non-random appearance, including some prominent dark lines, notably the lines given by the polynomials $4n^2\pm2n+41$.

Answer (score 0):

The Ulam spiral is formed by the numbers written in the form $6n \pm 1$. In other words, any number that is not a multiple of 2 and 3 is written in this format. Therefore any prime greater than 3 will have the form $6n \pm 1$. Because the primes are dense at the beginning they cover many of these points in the Ulam spiral. As we move into larger range of numbers, the primers are diluted and the Ulam spiral fades.